# explanation of curried connect call with redux

Tags: redux

I am looking at [this code](https://github.com/wbuchwalter/ng-redux/blob/master/examples/async/containers/app.js#L14) in an ng-redux example

```
class AppController {
  constructor($ngRedux, $scope, AsyncActions) {
    const unsubscribe = $ngRedux.connect(this.mapStateToThis, AsyncActions)((selectedState, actions) => {
      this.componentWillReceiveStateAndActions(selectedState, actions);
      Object.assign(this, selectedState, actions);
    });
    this.options = ['angularjs', 'frontend'];
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleRefreshClick = this.handleRefreshClick.bind(this);

    this.fetchPostsIfNeeded(this.selectedReddit);
  }

  componentWillReceiveStateAndActions(nextState, nextActions) {
    if (nextState.selectedReddit !== this.selectedReddit) {
      nextActions.fetchPostsIfNeeded(nextState.selectedReddit);
    }
  }
```

What is the purpose of the function that is called from the function that is returned from the initial connect call?

Is this in the redux docs?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, currying is used to cache some intermediate result. It makes your code more optimal in some cases.

In this example, it allows you to create connection once and then subscribe/unsubscribe it whenever you want.

```
class AppController {
  constructor($ngRedux, $scope, AsyncActions) {
    this.handler = $ngRedux.connect(this.mapStateToThis, AsyncActions);
  }

  activate() {
    this.removeHandler = this.handler(this.onUpdate)
  }

  deactivate() {
    this.removeHandler();
    this.removeHandler = null;
  }

  onUpdate() {
  }
}
```